Window focus and blur events not working properly in chrome
I have very simple code to log some message on window focus and blur events. It works fine on edge, firefox and brave browser and is not working consistently in the chrome browser. Is there any workaround to overcome this? as i couldn't see any one mentioning this issue on internet. Below is my code.
Few times, i noticed it works and when the same page is opened in the new tab, the events are not fired
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Window Focus/Blur Logger</title>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            console.log('Window gained focus');
        });

        window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            console.log('Window  lost focus');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    </body>
</html>


what does "when the tab is duplicated" even mean?

@JaromandaX Right clicking on the tab and clicking the Duplicate option. Edited description have clarity

Oh, never seen that option before :p

You might be looking for the page visibility API instead

@Bergi that doesn't work either

This works perfectly fine for me on chrome. Do you see any errors in the console?
